# external jquery not recognizing views within views - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-plugins, slider

I am trying to add a slider in the page.

I already have external jquery called in the header.php

```
<script src="<?php echo ASSETS_URL. "/js/libs/swiper.jquery.min.js"; ?>"></script>
```

and in my m_listing.php, I have the code

```
<li data-src="<?php echo base_url().'earnings/listings?mlid='.$list['m_listing_id']?>"></li>
```

and in earnings.php, I have function

```
function listings()
{
    $m_id = $this->input->get('mlid',TRUE);
    $val = $this->Earnings_Model->getSites($m_id);
    $data['val'] = $val;
    $this->load->view("site_work_page/lstng_01_rsite",$data);
}
```

then in the lstng_01_rsite, I have added class that are necessary for the plug-in.

```
swiper-container
swiper-wrapper
swiper-slide
swiper-button-next
swiper-button-prev
```

But it won't run, I think it cannot detect, how can I make it work?

Comment: What is your `ASSETS_URL`..?

Comment: Right click and inspect an element to bring up the developers console in Chrome. Then reload the page keeping the tab open, go to the console tab in the developers console and view there to see if any of the files are returning 404